# Roman Numeral 2 (II) under Bundesadler

Tags: style

I have a west german military greatcoat that I found on ebay. On the shoulder there is a patch  with the Bundesadler and a roman number 2 (II) underneath it. What does this mean? I was hoping to narrow down the production year to something smaller than 1950-1990.

I know this isn't strictly language translation, but it is sort of translation of symbols, yes?

Comment: A picture (even taken with a cellphone) would help.

Comment: [Das hier?](http://de.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Datei:Bundeswehr_Uniform_Paspel_01.jpg&filetimestamp=20070729161130)

Comment: I'm really not sure whether this is language related. Let's see where it is going...

Comment: @EvanCordell I agree to musiKk and I'm still unsure, if I will vote for close. But it would be easy to rephrase this question, so that it is about language. (Hint: If I am right with the posted picture, you could ask, how this sign is called, because it has a name. And in addition you can ask about the sense of this sign ;p)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean this sign:

[image]

It's the Coat of Arms (Ärmelabzeichen) of the [2nd Corps of the Bundeswehr](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/II._Korps_%28Bundeswehr%29).

Comment: That's it! Thanks. Unfortunately it still doesn't help me determine how old the coat is, the range is about the same.